# Rebuild a bootable kernel in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, boot-loader

I use archlinux for quite a while, and after a week since the last update I have done, I have launched a `pacman -Syu`, but, while updating my `LaTeX mappings`, my computer freezed with messages suggesting a read-only file system.

After rebooting, I have got a:

```
Loading Linux linux ...
error: premature end of file /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I have tried to boot on a LiveUSB, reinstall `linux` (even upgrading from `linux-5.11.2.arch1-1` to `linux-5.11.4.arch1-1`) and running `mkinitcpio -P`, but nothing changed.

I have plenty of space on all my partitions. I use GRUB, and I do not have a dual-boot.

What can I do next to have a bootable kernel?

Comment: Did you mount your boot partition to /mnt/boot before running `arch-chroot /mnt` and reinstalling linux?

Comment: Where is your boot partition mounted? And is this a EFI or legacy boot system?

Comment: @stefan0xC I did, I also deleted `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` to be sure it was recreated.

Comment: @JasonCroyle it is an EFI boot system, on the first partiton